# Como colocar o estilo do meu template em módulo extra?

Tags: joomla

Eu estou montando um site com um template Joomla (Youjoomla) e precisei instalar módulos extras para atender às minhas necessidades.

Como eu posso inserir o estilo do template utilizado para esses novos módulos?

Comment: Você quer mudar somente o CSS ou quer mudar a estrutura de apresentação no HTML?

Answer (score -1):

No módulo extra, defina o class-sufix com alguma propriedade de css que esteja definida no seu template.